# How can I use JavaScript with mdl-layout--fixed-tabs

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, angular-material, material-design-lite

I looked at numerous examples of `mdl-layout--fixed-tabs usage`.

I can't find any example of using `mdl-layout--fixed-tabs` with JavaScript. My goal is to make different REST backend calls depending on active tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDL is just a collection of CSS classes, each applied to an HTML element.

JavaScript is used to manipulate the HTML underneath the MDL classes, so you just use JavaScript with MDL like you would with regular HTML.

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1"); // Where tab1 is the ID of
                                            // of your HTML element with
                                            // the applied MDL class.
// Do whatever else you need to do, etc...
```

Comment: I might still be missing something. I am using angularjs with mdl. ng-click does not seem to be recognized.